# Sorting and showing the most repeated row (value)

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, sorting

I have a sheet containing over 200k+ rows with values like this,

```
10.10.10.10
11.11.11.11
12.12.12.12
10.10.10.10
10.10.10.10
```

I want to be able to show the most repeated row at the top or extract it to another sheet / file so I can view the most repeated value, something like,

```
10.10.10.10
10.10.10.10
10.10.10.10
11.11.11.11
12.12.12.12
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume the values in your example are in a single column.  If so the following steps will work assuming the data is in column A:

In column B enter the following formula: "=COUNTIF(A:A,A1)" and copy down to the bottom of your data range.  This will give the following result using your example data:

10.10.10.10 | 3

11.11.11.11 | 1

12.12.12.12 | 1

10.10.10.10 | 3

10.10.10.10 | 3

Sort on column B and done

10.10.10.10 | 3

10.10.10.10 | 3

10.10.10.10 | 3

11.11.11.11 | 1

12.12.12.12 | 1

Comment: It gives me error that the command is incorrect, here is some rows from the actual file `59.127.58.91
58.143.123.98
58.143.123.98
59.126.198.116
59.126.150.163
1.34.74.29
59.127.58.91
59.126.122.62
59.126.133.41
58.140.118.34
59.126.29.102
58.143.123.98
58.140.118.34
89.201.51.254
58.143.123.98
59.126.162.108`  each IP on its own row.

Comment: Formula looks good to me. What exact error do you get? At what point?